# How can I make this model?

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, scripting

[image]

I added a torus and I was trying to extrude the faces but I couldn't get the exact shape!
Should I continue with torus or circle will be much better?
**How can I make the part (circled in red) shown in the image?**

**P.S.  I have to use python scripting to make this model**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Torus go to edit mode. Select a loop and confirm that you're in face selection as shown in the GIF.

[image: Gif of solution]

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth(nth=3, offset=0)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 0.5), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
```

Comment: how can i select a loop of torus using python?

Comment: Go to Edit mode --- select a single face -- then run ---------  import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='PERIMETER', threshold=0.01)

Comment: cant i automate the whole process?

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you but how can i select that single face using python?

Answer (score 0):

For 1 click script [image]
Add torus and go to edit mode. Then select a single face (confirm that ur in face selection) and run

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.faces_select_linked_flat(sharpness=0.261799)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_nth(nth=3, offset=0)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, 0.5), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
```

If you just want to select a face loop
Add a torus and go to edit mode. Then select a single face (confirm that you are in face selection) and run

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.faces_select_linked_flat(sharpness=0.261799)
```

[image]

Comment: instead of adding a new answer, edit the previous one to add more detail.